# Why wp_schedule function in wordpress not work?

Tags: php, wordpress, schedule

I understand that the wp_schedule function will make a cron like ajax running on background when you open a browser tab and not close it. So, why my function could not get it work ?

I changed my coumputer time = my wordpress setting time = the GMT time in php.ini. But it still not work, below is my code. I putted it inside a wordpress plugin. So what i have to do ?

```
class CronTest {

function __construct() {
    add_action( 'init', array ( $this, 'g_order_sync' ) );
    add_action( 'ga_order_syn', array ( $this, 'sync_order' ) );
}

// init

public function g_order_sync() {
    try{
        if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'ga_order_syn' ) ) {
            wp_schedule_event(  time() + 10, null, 'ga_order_syn' );
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        echo "<p>The error: " . $e->getMessage() . "</p>"; //display error
    }
}

// cron job

public function sync_order() {
    $content = time() . ": some text here";
    $this->_write_content ($content);
}

// write content

private function _write_content( $content = '') {
    $path =  $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] . "/myText.txt";
    if( is_writable($path)) {
        $original = file_get_contents($path);
        $original .= PHP_EOL . $content;
        $fp = fopen( $path, "wb" );
        fwrite( $fp, $original );
        fclose( $fp );
    } else {
        // log error here
    }
}
}

// must initialize the cron class
$cron_test = new CronTest();
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress checks if it is have cron tasks only when somebody visits site. If you set you next event in 2 min to run and next access to your site will be in 10 hours, then your event will be fired in 10 hours (immediately with the access) but not in 2 minutes.

It is not like ajax and doesn't need your browser open. WP_Cron runs in the background.

If your site is accessed quite often, you can be assured that planned event will run at selected time.

**UPDATE**

What is wrong with your code.

`wp_schedule_event` is called improperly.

First argument is to define time of the first event execution. It is in milliseconds from the beginning of UNIX epoch (1-Jan-1970). What you are doing, you tell to make the first run of your event in 10 millisecinds from now. No problem by the way, WordPress will do it as soon as it can, but time()+10 has no sense at all. Just leave time() as 1st parameter.

Second argument cannot be null. It has to specify recurrence of your event. WordPress has 3 predefined intervals: hourly, twicedaily and daily. If none of them is appropriate, then you have to setup it in special hook:

```
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'example_add_cron_interval' );

function example_add_cron_interval( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['ten_seconds'] = array(
        'interval' => 10,
        'display'  => esc_html__( 'Every Ten Seconds' ),
    );

    return $schedules;
}
```

This example sets interval `ten_seconds` which can be used in `wp_schedule_event`. Finally, your call should look like that:

```
wp_schedule_event(  time(), 'ten_seconds', 'ga_order_syn' );
```

Comment: I have extended the answer.

Comment: Hey you, i got it successful. But my code just wok if i remove : if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'wpwhosonline_update' ) ) {. But if i don't remove it, it will run duplicate multi time.